# How to sum two subqueries count in third variable mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to sum total likes and comments but result is always zero (0)
please help me to resolve this issue because i have implemented mostly solutions that I find but no success.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,name,picture,
(SELECT COUNT(id) from likes) as likes,
(SELECT COUNT(id) from comments) as comments,
(likes+comments) as total
From users
```

Comment: You need to join the likes and comments tables to the users table to do this.  Can you provide more detail about your table structure?

Comment: It will overkill your performance. Try joins or provide a table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use column aliases in the same `SELECT` where they are defined.  I would suggest doing this in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.name, u.picture, l.likes, c.comments,
       (l.likes + c.comments) as total
FROM users u CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(id) as likes FROM likes) l CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(id) as comments FROM comments) c;
```

Presumably, `u.id` is unique.  If so, you should drop the `SELECT DISTINCT`.  It just adversely affects performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,name,picture,
(SELECT COUNT(id) from likes) as likes,
(SELECT COUNT(id) from comments) as comments,
(SELECT COUNT(id) from likes)+(SELECT COUNT(id) from comments) as total
From users
```